# Jquery drop down menu, how to position within my container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a fixed position menu at the top of my page, inside it is a div with the menu items and a .container class in order to center and limit the width. I can't seem to figure out how to limit my drop down menu to stay with in the .container class width limits. It keeps going off towards the right and will be cut off depending on page widths. Any help is really appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/rKaPN/47/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rKaPN/51/

Changed:

```
//fixed so submenu will be relative to menuitem
.menu ul li{
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

//if a rightmenu, float right instead of left
li.menu-right.drop-down ul{
    display:block !important;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to make sure that your `.container` is using a percentage based width.

Your menu is floating to the right of the container... so if the container is set to `500px`, but your browser is `400px`, your menu is going to get cut off.